# Convert number to time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, time

Is there any built in function in JavaScript or jQuery to convert number to time?

Ex:1) my input string is - 1350
expected output - 1:50 PM

Ex:2) input - 125
output - 1:25 PM

Ex:3) input - 4
output - 4:00 AM

Comment: I think you meant to type this question into Google

Comment: Try with MomentJS, maybe it has a function for that.

Comment: @yuriy636 yes momentJs can do that: `moment('1350', 'hmm').format("HH:mm a") === "13:50 pm"`

Comment: MomentJS is opensource?

Comment: @jestges yes it is: [momentJs](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: thank you, that resolves my issue :)

Comment: @empiric: That works for the first example, but not for the next two.

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in way to convert numbers to times in JavaScript, but it does not do the conversion in the way you're asking. What you're asking for is highly non-standard, and in fact highly problematic (e.g. what input would give you `1:25 AM`? what input would give you `12:04 AM`?).

You'll need to refine your requirements so they're not too ambiguous to implement, and then write your own code based on this one-off concept of time formatting.